# How required my class to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my class which is in file.rb I want to require this class in my project, I put this file into project/lib but when I call create new object, rails raises an error. You class absent. May be I not right assigned my file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

files in your lib folder are not auto-required. You have to put the requirement into an initializer (just check some of the existing initializers to see how to do it).

Comment: Yes, it's generic. There's an easy standard way to do it, which I pointed out in my answer (added after down vote).

Answer (score 1):

In `config/application.rb` around line 14 you have something like

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

uncomment and eventually edit the second of those lines.